# Equivalent of python 'pass' in drracket

Tags: scheme, racket

Does anyone know if DrRacket has got an equivalent of Python's `pass` statement or any other idiom that can be used to instruct the executing code to do nothing?

Comment: Can you show us a sniplet of code that demonstrates what you have. Looking at the comment of the first answer gives me a hunch you lack a check if key exist in the function you pass to map (or fold), but without any code I'm tumblingin the dark. Since you brought up python you might as well include a sniplet ofthe same (that works) in python too.

Comment: You can generally (always?) avoid using "pass" or "nop" statements by correctly defining the conditions in your program, besides all expressions will have a value in Scheme, even if it's void. In Python `pass` is unavoidable as a placeholder, but I doubt you'll ever need an equivalent statement in Scheme (it doesn't exist) ... as long as the program logic is correct

Comment: By the way, Racket is the name of the language. DrRacket is the name of the IDE that ships with Racket.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write an empty statement (one with no useful result), maybe this will work for you:

```
(void)
```

... But it'd be better if you demonstrated with an example what exactly is that you want to do. Anyway, here's a link to the appropriate section in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html).

Comment: Its a case of wanting to indexing a hash map with a key that may or may not exist so if a no key found error returns, I just want to ignore the error and continue with the execution.

Comment: Please post the code, and make it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Notice that a call to `(void)` _will_ return a value, `#<void>` and depending on what you're doing it might not be the right thing to do. I believe you're approaching the problem incorrectly, it'd be better to check first if the key exists

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do your hash example.

```
(hash-ref (hash) "not there" void)
```

But now you have to check whether you get back a `void` or a value you want. You may also be interested in `hash-update!` or `hash-update` ([docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html?q=hash#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/more-scheme..rkt%29._hash-update!%29%29)), which combines checking for an existing key with a default behavior for the case where the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

As I write this answer, your question is kind of spread among (a) your original question and (b) your comment to Oscar's answer:

> Its a case of wanting to indexing a hash map with a key that may or may not exist so if a no key found error returns, I just want to ignore the error and continue with the execution.

Taking that last part literally: The general way to handle -- and effectively "ignore" -- an exception is `with-handlers`:

```
(hash-ref (hash) "nothing")
;; hash-ref: no value found for key
;; key: "nothing"

(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                             "hum dee dum")])
  (hash-ref (hash) "nothing"))
;; "hum dee dum"
```

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with [Python `pass` as described here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html), but maybe `pass` can be used to ignore errors in Python; I just don't know it well enough

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with a syntactic form, then `begin` works.

```
(if <conditional> (begin))
```

if you need a function then this works

```
(lambda ignore #f)
```

And you might just avoid the need for 'something that does nothing' by reworking your logic leading to the 'nothing'.